# Dynamically allocate a stdlib stack?

Tags: c++, stack, std, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to use the stdlib stack in a class that I have created, but I am having issues creating it dynamically.

Here is the relevant code from my header file "matcher.h":

```
    private:

        stack<char> opens;
```

and here is the constructor that I am creating that only allocates the stack:

```
#include "matcher.h"
using namespace std;
//Creates a matcher object with the default values.
matcher::matcher()
{
    opens = new stack<char>;
}
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
matcher.cpp:19:17: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((matcher*)this)->matcher::opens = ((*(const std::deque<char, std::allocator<char> >*)(& std::deque<char, std::allocator<char> >())), (operator new(40u), (<statement>, ((std::stack<char>*)<anonymous>))))’
```

This says to me that the `std::stack` does not contain an assignment operator, which leads me to my question:

**What method should I use in order to get a stack that will persist within my matcher object if it does not contain an assignment operator?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you transition from Java or C#, you need a C++ course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opens` is an object within the class, and so does not need to be allocated with `new`.

If you want it to be default-constructed, then that will happen automatically - you don't need to write any code to do that. If all the class members can be default constructed, then you don't need to write a default-constructor for the class at all.

If you have a member that can't (or shouldn't) be default constructed, then you do that in the constructor's initialiser list, for example:

```
class matcher {
public:
    matcher() :
        number(42) // initialise with a value
    {}             // nothing else to do - "opens" is automatically initialised

private:
    stack<char> opens;
    int number;
};
```

Only use `new` when you really need a dynamically allocated object, and make sure it gets deleted once you've finished with it - preferably using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), since it's often hard to get it right any other way. If you want it to be tied to the lifetime of another object, then just place it inside that class as a member and don't bother with dynamic allocation.

Comment: Yes, thank you. For some reason I thought you needed to allocate it when you created the class.

Answer (score 2):

`new` always returns a *pointer* to the type you specify.  `opens` needs to be a `stack<char> *`.

But are you sure that you need to dynamically allocate the stack? A private member variable that you can create in the constructor rarely needs to be dynamically allocated. If you do allocate it dynamically, you should `delete` it in a destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result of new which would be a pointer to a stack. In other words you are trying to assign a stack* to a stack.

Secondly, why are you even doing this? A stack would be allocating it's elements on the heap anyway. No need for new.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a `stack<char>*`, which is what `new stack<char>` returns, to a `stack<char>` variable. Instead, you should use the following constructor:

```
// look ma, no need for new!
matcher::matcher()
{
}
```

and just rely on the default initialization of `opens`. The stack will be appropriately destroyed when your `matcher` object is.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems here.

```
private:
    stack<char> opens;
```

This means that you either have a `using namespace std;` in your header (extremely bad form) or you are requiring that one have a `using namespace std;` statement before including the header (even worse form).

The other problem is the immediate cause of your compiler error. You should not be allocating that `opens` stack. To be able to allocate `opens` would require declaring it as `std::stack<char>* opens;` -- and this, too, is something you generally don't want to do. With the declaration as is, `std::stack<char> opens;`, the variable already exists. It merely needs to be constructed. If you don't specify how to construct the object in your constructor's initializer list, the default constructor will be used by default.